# To generate a list for each map key as iterating through list?

Tags: groovy, syntax

I have a map and i need to insert a generated list to each map key in groovy as i am iterating through a list !

**Code:**

```
def myMap = [:]
    anotherList.each{
    object -> //here i do some work to get two elements
    def element1 = ..
    def element2 = ..

    // so here i need to generate a list for the two elements with index 0 and 1
    myMap[obejct]= ['list', my list] 
    }
   return myMap
```

Comment: What do you want as the key of your resulting map? Can you give an example input? Can you give an example output? Without these, everyone is guessing as it's hard to tell from the question exactly what you are expecting as an answer

Comment: if u look in my code so the object is the key of the map and the generated list of the two elements is the value !

Comment: Unfortunately, I still don't understand what you are trying to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a map using `[ key: value]` notation. Since your value is an array of two elements you can simply create it using `[element1,element2]` notation, and then you can add the object to the map using [`<<`  operator](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Map.html#leftShift(java.util.Map)).

So this `myMap << [ (object) :  [element1,element2]]` can do the job.

In your code:

```
   def myMap = [:]
    anotherList.each{
    object -> //here i do some work to get two elements
    def element1 = ..
    def element2 = ..

    // so here i need to generate a list for the two elements with index 0 and 1
     myMap << [ (object) :  [element1,element2]]
    }
   return myMap
```

Note that I use `(object)` to evaluate the key, because if I use directly `object` the literal is used as key in the map instead of the value.

Hope this helps,

**UPDATED BASED ON OP COMMENT:**

If I understand well your requirements you want that map keys are the index instead of the value isn't it? To do so you can use `eachWithIndex` instead of `each` for example:

```
def myMap = [:]
  def anotherList = ['a','b','c','d']
    anotherList.eachWithIndex{ object,index -> //here i do some work to get two elements
    def element1 = object + 'z'
    def element2 = object + 'x'

    // so here i need to generate a list for the two elements with index 0 and 1
     myMap << [ (index) :  [element1,element2]]
    }
   return myMap //Result: [0:[az, ax], 1:[bz, bx], 2:[cz, cx], 3:[dz, dx]]
```

Comment: thanks for help ! i just need the elements to be defined in specific index within the list ! so i can use each element based on its index

Comment: @Mich sorry I misunderstand your requirement. What do you mean? use index instead of `"$object"` as your key in the map?

Comment: i mean in the list of the two elements that used as map value  ! one element should be with index 0 and the other with index 1

Comment: Maybe am a bit confused and i confused u ! in the first approach do the element1 and element2 have a fixed index in that list ?

Comment: @Mich yes, the list always have a predefined index, try it: `def list = ['a','b'];
list[0] // returns 'a'.`. `:)`

Comment: That should've been obvious ! :) thanks for ur help ! so the first approach should work with me then ! sorry for confusing u !

Comment: @Mich don't worry, nice to help you `:)`

Comment: @albciff if you need to index a map with an object ( not just the toString value of the object, wrapped in a GString), you should use [(object): [element1,element2]]. I don't know if they have worked around this in groovy since, but using a GString as an key in a Map used to be a sin, because GStrings are not immutable, and their hashcodes can differ.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the method `collect` to go through your list and generate another list whose values depend on the original list (the reasoning you use inside this method is up to you. Here a small example:

```
    def originalList = [1,2,3]
    def result = originalList.collect{obj->
        def e1 = obj
        def e2 = obj*2
        [e1,e2]
    }
    println result //[[1,1],[2,4],[3,6]]
```

EDIT: Sorry, I overlooked the fact that you expect a map as result. Here is an approach similar to the one described above. In this case you use `each` to go through the elements of your list:

```
def originalList = [[name: 'franz', age: 12], [name: 'bepi', age: 20],[name: 'giovanni', age: 65]]
def result=[:]
originalList.each{obj->
    def e1 = obj.age
    def e2 = obj.age*2
    result.put(obj, [e1,e2]) //key, value
}
println result //[[name:franz, age:12]:[12, 24], [name:bepi, age:20]:[20, 40], [name:giovanni, age:65]:[65, 130]]
```